# How to Export Google Org Chart to PNG

Tags: pdf, google-visualization, png, orgchart

I am using Google Org Chart (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart) for rendering charts in my web app. I add custom formatting to my org chart nodes.

I want to add the ability to save the org chart as PNG. For this purpose I tried using the built-in feature to export to PNG (https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing).

However, all the formatting of the org chart is lost when I export it to PNG using the method described above. I want to export it so that the org chart look and feel is preserved completely in the export.

Any pointers on how this can be achieved?

Comment: This is an “I want a pony” question and because no specific technical answer can be given it’s off-topic here on Stack Overflow. You’ll need to attempt to solve this problem and show your code so we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level as well as to demonstrate your commitment to solving this problem. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: you can use [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) instead of the chart's native method `getImageURI` -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48686220/5090771) for an example...

Comment: @xdev Have you got any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to print the org chart which caused the same issue. Resolved it by including the CSS file

```
function printDiv() 
{
var divToPrint=document.getElementById('chart_div');
var newWin=window.open('','Print-Window');
newWin.document.open();
newWin.document.write('<html>');
newWin.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/OrgChart.css" type="text/css" />');
newWin.document.write('<body onload="window.print)">'+divToPrint.innerHTML+'</body></html>');
newWin.document.close();
setTimeout(function(){newWin.close();},10);
}
```

---

HTML

```
<div id="tools"><a onclick=printDiv();>Print</a></div>
```