# Export Google visualization as picture

Tags: html, charts, google-visualization, png

I'm trying to convert a wordtree Google visualization to an image. The current code below runs the wordtree so I can see the visual, but I can't figure out the last section to convert to an image or export as an image. (var my_div = section to end)

I have tried changing code from link below, but can't get it to save as an image.
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing

I'm also doing this inside of jsfiddle.net to try and make this work.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current');   // Don't need to specify chart libraries!
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
      function drawVisualization() {
        google.visualization.drawChart({
         "containerId": "mywordtree",
         "dataSourceUrl": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vi-YzV7s7eZ25938Q57DbZvT0iqggiCqRvDgxeZtP6c/edit?usp=sharing",
         "query":"SELECT A",
         "chartType": "WordTree",
         "options": {
                wordtree: {
            format: 'implicit',
            //alt type is 'suffix', 'prefix'
            type: 'suffix',
            word: 'prescription'
            }
         }
       });
      }

    var my_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var my_chart = new google.visualization.ChartType(mywordtree);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(my_chart, 'ready', function () {
      mywordtree.innerHTML = '<img src="' + my_chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    });

    my_chart.draw(data);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="mywordtree" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, in order to generate an image of the chart,
you need to wait for the chart's `'ready'` event.

in order to wait for the `'ready'` event,
you need access to the chart object.

you will not be able to use the [`google.visualization.drawChart`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.drawchart) method,
because it does not return a handle to the chart.

next, the `WordTree` chart, does not have a [method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/wordtree#methods) for `getImageURI`,
so you will need to create the image manually, from a `blob`.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current').then(function () {
  // get chart container
  var container = document.getElementById('mywordtree');

  // create chart
  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'WordTree',
    containerId: container.id,
    dataSourceUrl: 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vi-YzV7s7eZ25938Q57DbZvT0iqggiCqRvDgxeZtP6c/edit?usp=sharing',
    options: {
      wordtree: {
        format: 'implicit',
        //alt type is 'suffix', 'prefix'
        type: 'suffix',
        word: 'prescription'
      }
    }
  });

  // listen for ready event
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var domUrl;    // object url
    var image;     // chart image
    var imageUrl;  // chart image url
    var svg;       // svg element

    // add svg namespace to chart
    svg = container.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
    svg.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');

    // create image url from svg
    domUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
    imageUrl = domUrl.createObjectURL(new Blob([svg.outerHTML], {type: 'image/svg+xml'}));

    // create chart image
    image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      // replace chart with image
      container.innerHTML = image.outerHTML;
    }
    image.src = imageUrl;
  });

  // draw chart
  chart.draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="mywordtree"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps. note: the above code to get the image will not work in IE, you can use `html2canvas` instead, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48686220/5090771) for an example...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had been reading some things about some of the visualizations not working with the getImageURI, so this is helpful to see how to resolve the issues. Thanks again.